# Implode with default value if no values

Tags: php

I want to show dash(-) if my array is empty after imploding it. Here below is my try so far.

Result with Data in Array -> https://repl.it/HIUy/0

```
<?php 

$array = array(1,2);
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $curr_arr) {

    $result[] = $curr_arr;
}
echo 'Array With Data - ' .  implode(',', $result);
//Result : Array With Data : 1,2   
?>
```

Result without Data in Array -> https://repl.it/HIVE/0

```
<?php 

$array = array();
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $curr_arr) {

    $result[] = $curr_arr;
}
echo 'Array Without Data - ' .  implode(',', $result);
//Result : Array With Data - :    
?>
```

As you can see in the second result, I am unable to print anything as my array was blank hence I was unable to print anything.

However, I want to print **Dash(-)** using `implode` only by using something like `array_filter` which I already tried but I am unable to do so. Here I have tried this https://repl.it/HIVP/0

```
<?php 

$array = array();
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $curr_arr) {

    $result[] = $curr_arr;
}
echo 'Array With Data : ' .  implode(',', array_filter($result));
//Result : Array With Data :    
?>
```

Can someone guide me how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: post the code as part of your question

Comment: `if (empty(YOUR_ARRAY))`

Comment: `echo 'Array Without Data - ' .  (implode(',', $result)?:'-');`

Comment: @u_mulder i already know this but i want to do inside implode using callback or something like this without if condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if your array is empty and then return/ echo a Dash:

```
if(!empty($array)){
  // Array contains values, everything ok
  echo 'Array with data - ' . implode('yourGlueHere', $array);
} else {
  // Array is empty
  echo 'Array without data -';
}
```

If you want to have it in one line, you could do something like the following:

```
echo 'Array with' . empty($array) == false ? '' : 'out' . 'data - ' . empty($array) == false ? implode('glue', $array) : '';
```

Comment: I already know this but i want to do inside implode using callback or something like this without if condition.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave implode has only two parameters, `glue` and `pieces`, there isn't any callback. or why don't you just create an custom helper function using any of the answers in this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Answers posted by Tobias F. and Gopi Chand is correct.

**Approach 1**:
I'd suggest you going this way would help you (Basically using ternary operator).
As here is no other way of doing this using just implode function.

```
echo empty($result) ? '-' : implode(',',$result);
```

**Approach 2**
Using a helper function like this.

```
function myImpllode($glue = "", $array = [])
{
   if(!empty($array)){
   // Array contains values, everything ok
   return implode($glue, $array);
   } else {
   // Array is empty
   return '-';
   }
}
```